# how to write styles for an input when it is selected

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

i am stuck in a screen style like below as in the screen shot there are for input(image) elements i want them to be bordered same like in the image with circled tick mark. i've made these four input block but dont know how to style this when the user click on it (i mean when user clicks on it , it gets the same border and tick mark with as it is and input)
[image: input type is image]

Note: i'm working in Reactjs MUI

i have tried this

```
div:focus {
 border 2px solid #908098
}
```

but i dont know how to make that circled tick.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: It would be easy to understand the issue if you can create a runnable sample with what is the expected output and share the link, you can use codesandbox / stackblitz / w/e works for you  (add code, save and share the link)

Comment: in the above attached picture it is clear, i think. like when i selected the admin option it will have a blur border and that tick on it. so my question is about the css to write for it.

Comment: It's not clear because we only know that you are using `Reactjs MUI` and `input` of some kind. Is it `<input type="radio">`?

Comment: though i've mentioned in first line like this input(image) ,well let me explain it is an <input type="image"> i just want to ask the css of this type or border with ticked circle? hope you get it now.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your HTML was structured like so:

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="option" id="admin">
        <!-- content -->
    </div>
    <div class="option" id="moderator">
        <!-- content -->
    </div>
    <div class="option" id="chat-agent">
        <!-- content -->
    </div>
    <div class="option" id="custom">
        <!-- content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

To get the circled tick onto each option when it is in `focus`, you could add the tick icon to each option's `:after` pseudo-element, and then toggle the visibility on or off, depending on weather the option is in `focus` or not.

Here's the CSS:

```css
.option:after {
    content: '';
    background: url('path/to/tick-icon.ico');
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px; /* set the width and height to the dimensions of your tick icon */

    display: none; /* make pseudo-element invisible by default */
}

.option:focus {
    border 2px solid #908098;
}

.option:focus:after {
    display: initial;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the sub-class "focus" to select the exactly moment to add styles.
Example:

```css
.divClas:focus{
/*your code here*/
}
```